# C++ Matrix combinations

Tags: c++, matrix, combinations

Firstly thanks for reading.I'm trying to make a "noob" program and i wanted to use a registration code.
For completing my encryption algorythm i need to generate all 4x4 matrices containing only numbers from 0 to 9 like in the following example:

4 4 6 8

5 2 4 3

8 5 2 9

2 7 2 6

I know there is a huge number of these combinations but it wont stop me.I tried myself to do it using "for" but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Instead of just asking us for how to do it, post what you already have so we can help you improve. For a 4 by 4 matrix start off by creating a multi-dimension array.

Comment: that's 10^16 possible combinations. sure you don't wanna stop? :)

Comment: Do you need help with matrix math?

Comment: Storing that in memory will take almost 150,000 *terabytes* (assuming each number uses 1 char). I know you said that the huge number of combinations won't stop you, but memory requirements will.

Comment: i just don't know how to generate matrices with "counting" elements.

Comment: i wont save those matrices on my hdd lol.i will check each one to see if it fits my checking algorythm

Comment: Ok, change the analysis. If you checked one combination per clock cycle on your machine, it would take 31 days for a 3GHz machine to check every combination. Add that in with the fact that you will likely use MUCH more than one clock cycle per iteration, and you're in for a long wait.

Comment: You don't really know what you want to do. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the 4x4 digit matrix as char[16], interpreting the first four chars as the first row, the next four chars as the second row, etc.  You can easily generate all possible values by recursion, with a `for` loop on each level.

```
void print_all_possible_matrices(char *matrix, int level) {
    if(level == 16) {
        print_matrix(matrix);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        matrix[level] = i;
        print_all_possible_matrices(matrix, level + 1);
    }
}
```

You would use this in the following way:

```
int main() {
    char matrix[16];
    print_all_possible_matrices(matrix, 0);
}
```

But this will take really loooong time to complete.